# Converting timstamp to date in php returns a wrong date?

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to get the date from the following timestamp: 1410290399037

I have tried the following but I'm getting a wrong date

```
date('m-d-Y', 1410290399037); // output is: 04-28-46660
```

Also, I tried

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(1410290399037);
echo $date->format('m-d-Y');  // output is: 04-28-46660
```

I am getting the timestamp from a RESTFul web service. I am sure the timestamp is correct.

When I tested it in the following website http://www.epochconverter.com/, I got the right date

How can I get the right date value using PHP

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that `1410290399037` is in miliseconds where php uses seconds. Try dividing `1410290399037/1000`.

Comment: @imtheman - I +1'd you however isn't that the same as multiplying by 0.001, lol

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Yes, but your answer is still wrong...

Comment: @imtheman why is my answer wrong?  I posed the fact that the timestamp was wrong, showed how to verify that.  Posed a way to correct it.  Surly the OP can figure out how to divide or multiply correctly in PHP

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix You chopped off 4 digits which is dividing by 10,000 not 1,000.

Comment: @imtheman - Hmm seems right to me.  <Looks Around>

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix milliseconds * 0.001 = seconds.  milliseconds * 0.0001 is what you did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the timestamp you are getting is in miliseconds, but PHP uses seconds. Simply divide what ever you get by 1000 and it will work.

```
$timstamp = 1410290399037;
$date = date('m-d-Y', $timstamp/1000);
echo $date;
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that your timestamp is wrong.

I suggest trying an online unix timestamp converter to verify this such as

http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Which yields `Sat, 28 Apr 46660 13:03:57 GMT`

Chomping off the last 4 numbers ( as if it were milliseconds )

gives `Tue, 09 Sep 2014 19:19:59 GMT` for 1410290399, is that closer to what you expect?

Comment: got a -1 and no comment, that's classy